# Azure Keyvault - "Operation "list" is not allowed by vault policy" but all permissions are checked

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, azure, azure-keyvault

I am accessing KeyVault with .NET client with an AAD application. Although all permissions under secrets are enabled for this AAD app (screenshot below) I am getting "The operation "List" is not enabled in this key vault's access policy" if I navigate to the Secret panel.

I would like to be able to set the permissions via the AAD application and so using Powershell wouldn't be an option.

If I set the permissions via Powershell - it does work.

How I'm creating my access policies:

```
        var accessPolicy = new AccessPolicyEntry
        {

            ApplicationId = app,
            ObjectId = Obid,
            PermissionsRawJsonString = "{ \"keys\": [ \"all\" ], \"secrets\": [ \"all\"  ], \"certificates\": [ \"all\" ] }",
            TenantId = ten,

        };

        return accessPolicy;
```

which gives me
[image]

Then the list error appears and so I have to use

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName vaultname -ResourceGroupName location -ObjectId obid -PermissionsToKeys all -PermissionsToSecrets all
```

That will get rid of the error but I would much prefer a solution so I can work with the .NET SDK to resolve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After ages of trying to sort this issue - the problem was in the access policies code. When a user is registered in the code - it associates itself with the app ID. The app ID is the problem as it thinks that the user is an application AND a user.

The tell-tale sign of this is if you go into the portal, then "Access Policy" on a Keyvault and it'll say Application + User underneath. If you try and add a user (that is already on the list) - it will add the second user - so you'll have 2 of the same.

So all that's needed is to:

```
       var accessPolicy = new AccessPolicyEntry
    {

        ApplicationId = app, // Delete this line
        ObjectId = Obid,
        PermissionsRawJsonString = "{ \"keys\": [ \"all\" ], \"secrets\": [ \"all\"  ], \"certificates\": [ \"all\" ] }",
        TenantId = ten,

    };

    return accessPolicy;
```

The Microsoft documentation can be vague at times and I believe this is one of them.

Comment: Thanks for followup.  Yeah, sometimes the documentation has these small holes that take a while to figure out.

Answer (score 49):

[image]

Got the error:

> The operation "List" is not enabled in this key vault's access policy.
>
> You are unauthorized to view these contents.

The key here was to look at `You are unauthorized to view these contents.`

Navigate to `Access policies` and add your currently logged in user as principal with at least `List` privilege:

[image]

You can now view secrets if there are any:

[image]

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue and the solution was to get to my vault's `Access Policies` blade, then click on my application and activate `List` on `Key permissions` / `Secret permissions`